# Drawing from a Laplace distribution using Scipy yields negatively skewed density

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, kernel-density, skew

When I make draws from a Laplace distribution with mean zero and scale drawn from any distribution that maps into the positive orthant, the resulting empirical distribution is negatively skewed, regardless of the number of draws, distribution for the scale and seed. Regarding the large sample size symmetry is expected, however.
See the following two examples that can be reproduced

Example 0:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import halfcauchy
from scipy.stats import laplace

lam_0 = halfcauchy.rvs(loc=0, scale=1, size=2000000, random_state=77)
lap_0 = laplace.rvs(loc=0, scale=1 / lam_0, random_state=77)
np.quantile(lap_0, 0.05)
-22.130260524443447
np.quantile(lap_0, 0.95)
0.38451887570738214
np.mean(lap_0) 
-67.06943091954444
```

Example 1:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import expon
from scipy.stats import laplace

lam_1 = expon.rvs(loc=0, scale=2, size=1000000, random_state=42)
lap_1 = laplace.rvs(loc=0, scale=1 / lam_1, random_state=42)
np.quantile(lap_1, 0.05)
-29.27074349002619
np.quantile(lap_1, 0.95)
0.2953765780255653
np.mean(lap_1) 
-71.64564905737133
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both examples, you are giving the same integer `random_state` argument to the distribution.  So, for example, the generation of `lam_0` and `lap_0` are based on the same sequence of samples from the uniform distribution generated by the underlying random number generator.  This results in a correlation between the array that you give as the `scale` argument to `laplace.rvs()` and the uniform samples that `laplace.rvs()` uses to generate its samples--and that results in the negative values being large and the positive values being small.

If you use different `random_state` parameters, you get the distribution that you expect.  If you want reproducibility, you can create one generator instance, and pass it to both functions (so the underlying generator is generating new uniform samples in the call of `laplace.rvs()`).  For example,

```
In [252]: rng = np.random.default_rng(121263137472525314065)

In [253]: lam_0 = halfcauchy.rvs(loc=0, scale=1, size=2000000, random_state=rng)

In [254]: lap_0 = laplace.rvs(loc=0, scale=1/lam_0, random_state=rng)

In [255]: np.quantile(lap_0, 0.05)
Out[255]: -6.064955243909569

In [256]: np.quantile(lap_0, 0.95)
Out[256]: 6.111148574695757
```